# Select most recent test score on per month basis

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle SQL, and I'm trying to perform a historical test score analysis (to visualize test score improvements on per month basis for individuals). Firstly, I have a table that is a list of Users and the respective Months they are active; it looks something like this:

```
    TABLE1
    ________________________
    UserName  |  ActiveDate
    ________________________
    John Doe,    01-MAY-18
    John Doe,    01-APR-18
    John Doe,    01-MAR-18
    Jane Doe,    01-APR-18
    Jane Doe,    01-MAR-18
    Jim Doe,     01-MAY-18
```

On top of that, I have another table that lists Test Scores, which are timestamped (you can retake the test as many times as you want). It looks something like this:

```
    TABLE2
    ________________________________________
    UserName  |  TestScore  |  EffectiveDate
    ________________________________________
    John Doe,    87,           07-FEB-18
    John Doe,    85,           14-FEB-18
    John Doe,    90,           18-FEB-18
    John Doe,    92,           02-MAR-18
    John Doe,    91,           12-MAR-18
    Jane Doe,    70,           01-FEB-18
    Jane Doe,    72,           02-FEB-18
    Jane Doe,    78,           18-FEB-18
    Jane Doe,    77,           06-MAR-18
    Jane Doe,    81,           18-MAR-18
    Jim Doe,     50,           03-MAR-18
    Jim Doe,     48,           23-MAR-18
    Jim Doe,     58,           08-APR-18
```

For every row in the first table (all the UserName | ActiveDate pairings are disctinct), I would like to select the **most recent TestScore from Table2 where the EffectiveDate is prior to the ActiveDate**

So I'm hoping to get something like this

```
    UserName  |  ActiveDate  |  Most recent TestScore prior to ActiveDate
    ______________________________________
    John Doe,    01-MAY-18,     91
    John Doe,    01-APR-18,     91
    John Doe,    01-MAR-18,     90
    Jane Doe,    01-APR-18,     81
    Jane Doe,    01-MAR-18,     78
    Jim Doe,     01-MAY-18,     58
```

I've tried to make this work by **JOINING** Table1 to Table2 on UserName, where EffectiveDate < ActiveDate, but I can't seem to figure out the SQL statement I need to SELECT * from Table2 where EffectiveDate < ActiveDate, but I'm struggling to figure that out on a "per row" basis...

Thanks for any and all advice in advance. This is my first posting to StackOverflow, so I hope I've posed this question correctly!

Edit: Thanks all for the help, I think I have everything I need to proceed with my project now. I'll be sure to make some improvements to my posting next time I ask a question here on SO.

Comment: A couple of things that would improve your question. First, its nice that you posted your data as text (rather than images) but it would be even better to post it as a DDL/DML statement so we can easily recreate your data. Second, it would be great if your sample data and expected output matched so we could see how the data transforms (you have data from Feb/March in your input and March/April/May in your output for John Doe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions that only require a single join:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 ( UserName, ActiveDate ) AS
  SELECT 'John Doe', DATE '2018-05-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'John Doe', DATE '2018-04-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'John Doe', DATE '2018-03-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Jane Doe', DATE '2018-04-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Jane Doe', DATE '2018-03-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Jim Doe',  DATE '2018-05-01' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE TABLE2 ( UserName, TestScore, EffectiveDate ) AS
  SELECT 'John Doe', 87, DATE '2018-02-07' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'John Doe', 85, DATE '2018-02-14' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'John Doe', 90, DATE '2018-02-18' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'John Doe', 92, DATE '2018-03-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'John Doe', 91, DATE '2018-03-12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Jane Doe', 70, DATE '2018-02-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Jane Doe', 72, DATE '2018-02-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Jane Doe', 78, DATE '2018-02-18' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Jane Doe', 77, DATE '2018-03-06' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Jane Doe', 81, DATE '2018-03-18' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Jim Doe',  50, DATE '2018-03-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Jim Doe',  48, DATE '2018-03-23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Jim Doe',  58, DATE '2018-04-08' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t2.*,
         t1.ActiveDate,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY t2.UserName, t1.ActiveDate ORDER BY EffectiveDate DESC ) AS rn
  FROM   table2 t2
         INNER JOIN
         table1 t1
         ON ( t1.UserName = t2.UserName
              AND t2.EffectiveDate < t1.ActiveDate )
) t2
WHERE rn = 1;
```

**Output**:

```
USERNAME    TESTSCORE   EFFECTIVEDATE   ACTIVEDATE  RN
----------  ----------  --------------  ----------  ---
Jane Doe    78          18-FEB-18       01-MAR-18   1
Jane Doe    81          18-MAR-18       01-APR-18   1
Jim Doe     58          08-APR-18       01-MAY-18   1
John Doe    90          18-FEB-18       01-MAR-18   1
John Doe    91          12-MAR-18       01-APR-18   1
John Doe    91          12-MAR-18       01-MAY-18   1
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT t1.UserName,
       t1.ActiveDate,
       MAX( TestScore ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY EffectiveDate ) AS MostRecentTestScore
FROM   table2 t2
       INNER JOIN
       table1 t1
       ON ( t1.UserName = t2.UserName
            AND t2.EffectiveDate < t1.ActiveDate )
GROUP BY t1.UserName, t1.ActiveDate;
```

**Output**:

```
USERNAME    ACTIVEDATE  MOSTRECENTTESTSCORE
----------  ----------  -------------------
Jim Doe     01-MAY-18   58
Jane Doe    01-MAR-18   78
Jane Doe    01-APR-18   81
John Doe    01-MAR-18   90
John Doe    01-APR-18   91
John Doe    01-MAY-18   91
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the test score, a correlated subquery might be the simplest approach:

```
select t1.*,
       (select max(t2.score) keep (dense_rank first order by t2.effectivedate desc)
        from table2 t2
        where t2.effectivedate < t1.activedate
       ) as most_recent_score
from table1 t1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option (you need lines 24 onwards; previous lines are just testing CTEs):

```
SQL> with table1 (username, activedate) as
  2    (select 'jod', date '2018-05-01' from dual union all
  3     select 'jod', date '2018-04-01' from dual union all
  4     select 'jod', date '2018-03-01' from dual union all
  5     select 'jad', date '2018-04-01' from dual union all
  6     select 'jad', date '2018-03-01' from dual union all
  7     select 'jid', date '2018-05-01' from dual
  8    ),
  9  table2 (username, testscore, effectivedate) as
 10    (select 'jod', 87, date '2018-02-07' from dual union all
 11     select 'jod', 85, date '2018-02-14' from dual union all
 12     select 'jod', 90, date '2018-02-18' from dual union all
 13     select 'jod', 92, date '2018-03-02' from dual union all
 14     select 'jod', 91, date '2018-03-12' from dual union all
 15     select 'jad', 70, date '2018-02-01' from dual union all
 16     select 'jad', 72, date '2018-02-02' from dual union all
 17     select 'jad', 78, date '2018-02-18' from dual union all
 18     select 'jad', 77, date '2018-03-06' from dual union all
 19     select 'jad', 81, date '2018-03-18' from dual union all
 20     select 'jid', 50, date '2018-03-03' from dual union all
 21     select 'jid', 48, date '2018-03-23' from dual union all
 22     select 'jid', 58, date '2018-04-08' from dual
 23    )
 24  select t1.username, t1.activedate, t2.testscore
 25  from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.username = t2.username
 26  where t2.effectivedate = (select max(t2a.effectivedate)
 27                            from table2 t2a
 28                            where t2a.username = t2.username
 29                              and t2a.effectivedate < t1.activedate
 30                           )
 31  order by t1.username, t1.activedate desc;

USE ACTIVEDAT  TESTSCORE
--- --------- ----------
jad 01-apr-18         81
jad 01-mar-18         78
jid 01-may-18         58
jod 01-may-18         91
jod 01-apr-18         91
jod 01-mar-18         90

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```